# Refresh a page in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, refresh, native, reload

I am in a proyect and I need to filter some information in some diferent ways like ascendent, most recent and some other. For that, I have to refresh the page and send that info to the same page. This is the code where I want to put it:

```
<TouchableOpacity
  key='privacy'
  onPress={() => Actions.quicksearch({ searchval: this.state.searchval, searchlable: this.state.searchlab, text: this.state.text, order: 'asc' })}
>
  <Text style={styles.navmenuTitle}>
    Name (A-Z)
  </Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

I am redirecting it to the same page couse its the easiest way to do it but it opens as many pages as you want and all are the same pages with different filters. I also tried to use action.refresh but nothing happens.

Thank you!

Comment: React native use 're-render' to refresh screen, the content in react native component will change/rerender everytime the state is being change. If you want your components data change dynamically, make sure you know how to deal wit ur state.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Directly calling this.state.someVar =... does not trigger the refresh action. You can manually call:

```
this.forceUpdate();
```

But this is not recommended.

A better way is to call setState(...):

```
this.setState(...);      //Prefered

this.state.someVar = ... //Not recommended
this.forceUpdate()/      //Not recommended
```